# Commutator as a time-ordered product

Tags: string-theory, commutator, non-commutative-geometry

I'm reading through Seiberg and Witten's paper "[String Theory and Noncommutative Geometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep--th/9908142)," and one part in $\S$2.1 isn't quite clear to me.  (Sorry, in advance, for the length.)

My question is about equation (2.7) on page 9, where they say:

> The coefficient $\theta^{ij}$ in the propagator also has a simple intuitive interpretation, suggested in [[15]](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903205).  In conformal field theory, one can compute commutators of operators from the short distance behavior of operator products by interpreting time ordering as operator
>   ordering.  Interpreting $\tau$ as time, we see that
>
> $$ [x^i(\tau),x^j(\tau)]=T(x^i(\tau)x^j(\tau^-)-x^i(\tau)x^j(\tau^+))=i\theta^{ij}. \tag{2.7} $$

${}$

**Question:  How did they get the first equality?**

I'm sure that there is probably some really simple argument I'm not seeing, but, as this equation is the crucial step in which noncommutativity of coordinates appears, I figure I should probably understand it.  Any help?

---

The context is: consider a flat space (with metric $g_{ij}$) in the presence of a constant NS $B$-field with $Dp$-branes.  Further, for simplicity, they assume that $B_{0i}=0$, $B_{ij}\neq 0$ for $i,j=1,\cdots,r$, and $g_{ij}=0$ for $i=1,\cdots,r$ and $j\neq 1,\cdots,r$, where $r$ is the rank of the matrix $B_{ij}$.  Then one can obtain the action

$$ S=\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int_{\Sigma}\big(g_{ij}\partial_ax^i\partial^ax^j-2\pi i\alpha'B_{ij}\epsilon^{ab}\partial_ax^i\partial_bx^j\big) $$

(with $\Sigma$: the string worldsheet), which leads to the boundary conditions (along the $Dp$-branes): $g_{ij}\partial_nx^j+2\pi i\alpha'B_{ij}\partial_tx^j\big|_{\partial\Sigma}=0$ (where $n$ is the normal to $\partial\Sigma$).

Taking $\Sigma$ to be a disc, these become:

$$ g_{ij}(\partial-\bar{\partial})x^j+2\pi\alpha' B_{ij}(\partial+\bar{\partial})x^j\big|_{z=\bar{z}}=0. $$

Then, it was shown elsewhere that the propagator can be written:

$$ \langle x^i(z)x^j(z') \rangle = -\alpha'\bigg[g^{ij}\log|z-z'|-g^{ij}\log|z-\bar{z}'|+G^{ij}\log|z-\bar{z}'|^2 $$
$$ \hspace{3.4in}+\frac{1}{2\pi\alpha'}\theta^{ij}\log\frac{z-\bar{z}'}{\bar{z}-z'}+D^{ij}\bigg], $$

where $G_{ij}$ is the open string metric given by

$$ G_{ij}=g_{ij}-(2\pi\alpha')^2(Bg^{-1}B)_{ij} $$

so that

$$ G^{ij}= \bigg( \frac{1}{g+2\pi\alpha'B}g\frac{1}{g-2\pi\alpha'B} \bigg)^{ij}, $$

the constants $D^{ij}$ depend only on $B$ and "play no essential role and can be set to a convenient value," and

$$ \theta^{ij}=-(2\pi\alpha')^2\bigg( \frac{1}{g+2\pi\alpha'B}B\frac{1}{g-2\pi\alpha'B} \bigg)^{ij}. $$

Finally, they focus on open string vertex operators, restrict to real $z$ and $z'$ (which they then denote by $\tau$ and $\tau'$), and make a convenient choice of $D^{ij}$ so that the above propagator reduces to

$$ \langle x^i(\tau)x^j(\tau')\rangle = -\alpha'G^{ij}\log(\tau-\tau')^2+\frac{i}{2}\theta^{ij}\epsilon(\tau-\tau'). $$

Then the above claim about the commutator is made.

Comment: I think it is generally true that $T(A(t)B(t-\epsilon)-A(t)B(t+\epsilon))=A(t)B(t)-B(t)A(t)=[A(t),B(t)]$. Here $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimally small positive number. This is a common trick used to obtain (the expectation value of) equal time commutators.

Comment: Ah yes, just by definition!  That was easy.  It seems that I have rather selective memory when it comes to QFT.  :D  (which isn't surprising, as I actually study math, and only have a passing familiarity with it… perhaps I should fix that.)